# How can limit the content of the particular document hit on elastic search?

Tags: java, search, elasticsearch

`{
    "user": "dilbert",
    "postDate": "2011-12-12",
    "content": "Distribution is hard. Distribution should be easy." ,
    "title": "On distributed search"
}`

Now if do a search query on this document. i get the whole content. Lets say if the content is very big i want only particular portion of the content which got hits. whats the Api? I couldn't find it in docs of elastic search to limit the size or lines.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the size of the result set (number of results) by adding `size` to your root object, i.e.

```
{
  "size": 5,
  "query": {
     ...
  }
}
```

And if each result is too large and you want to get only specific fields, you can do it like so:

```
{
  "_source": {
    "include": [ "field1", "field2" ],
    "exclude": [ "field3" ]
  },
  "query": {
    ...
  "
}
```

Comment: Yes that is number of documents hits. what about limiting the size of the field content?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it through the highlight API. you cannot restrict the content size or character limits on the particular field.

this way you can get only the near by characters and you can configure for your character size.

`{
    "query" : {...},
    "highlight" : {
        "number_of_fragments" : 3,
        "fragment_size" : 150,
        "tag_schema" : "styled",
        "fields" : {
        }
}`